# Setting up a constructor

Tags: java

For an assignment, I am trying to set up a constructor for a concert attendee with String name, int age, and boolean is Vaccinated.  The code given (on paper only) is:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
class ConcertAttendee {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  public boolean isVaccinated;

  /* creates a new attendee and sets its data fields*/
  public ConcertAttendee(String name, int age, boolean isVaccinated) { }
}
```

I have

```java
public ConcertAttendee(String name, int age, boolean isVaccinated) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
   this isVaccinated = isVaccinated;
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: "Is this correct?" No, not quite. One of those lines is not like the others.

Comment: Can you specify the question? `Is this correct?` is rather broad

Comment: You're missing a `.` between `this` and `isVaccinated`.

Comment: "is this correct" ... the "correct" way to go about this question: run the compiler. That is the whole point of programming languages: they are supposed to be processed by computers. You see, this community is about specific questions on programming. It is not at all a replacement for you ... running the compiler. You see, learning programming is about many things. One of them: understanding the messages the compiler has to offer to you.

Comment: @AndyTurner There is a simple alternative: a 100% vaccination mandate. Then everybody can feel safe, while also everybody has to never talk about their personal vaccination status ;-)

Comment: Does `isVaccinated` refer to any vaccination ever received? Only to ones that still offer protection? Or only specific ones?

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct you should put a dot between this and isVaccinated. this.isVaccinated = isVaccinated

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct?

No. It will cause a compilation error.
Correct is like this ...

```
public ConcertAttendee(String name, int age, boolean isVaccinated) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
   this.isVaccinated = isVaccinated; // you need a dot after this and the field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ConcertAttendee(String name, int age, boolean isVaccinated) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
   this.isVaccinated = isVaccinated;
}
```

This is correct ^

Answer (score -1):

Here are couple of observations:

Form the code snipped you've shared, you don't need to import the `ArrayList`.

`this` refers to the current instance of the class. You need to access the fields using the dot notation.

```
public ConcertAttendee(String name, int age, boolean vaccinated) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
   this.vaccinated = vaccinated;
}
```

I'd suggest renaming `isVaccinated` to `vaccinated`. As per the Java POJO naming conventions, the boolean getters are named `is<field name>` here `isVaccinated()` should be the getter for `vaccinated` field in the class `ConcertAttendee`.